# string variables concatenated in SQL (to access DB), Syntax errors due to quotations?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I have 2 list boxes defining 2 variables that need to be passed to OpenRecordSet via a SQL statement.

**Conveyor_ID** is a access table name
**Width** is a field name in the table Conveyor_ID
**Width_Row** is a string value that values in the Field Width

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Const DbLoc As String = "DB location info"


Dim Conveyor_ID As String  ' Conveyor ID Table
Dim Width_Row As String    ' Width row, string values such as 12" or 12in

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM " & [Conveyor_ID] & " Where Width = " & [Width_Row])
```

Depending on which value is selected for the Width_row, I will get two different errors.

**If  ' 14in ' is selected,** 
error  of " In operator without () in query expression 'Width = 14in' "

**If  ' 14" ' is selected,**
 error  of " Syntax error in string in query expression 'Width = 12"'.

I believe I don't understand the syntax of adding variables to a SQL string that is getting passed onto a Openrecordset method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're passing the string without any quotation marks, and concatenating it with the SQL. This results in invalid SQL.

This means your final string might look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM someTable Where Width = 12in
```

That's not valid SQL. Strings in SQL need to be surrounded in single or double quotes.

There are multiple ways to go about this. The proper way is to use parameters.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
Const DbLoc As String = "DB location info"


Dim Conveyor_ID As String  ' Conveyor ID Table
Dim Width_Row As String    ' Width row, string values such as 12" or 12in
Set db = CurrentDb 'You were missing this in your sample
Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("", "SELECT * FROM " & [Conveyor_ID] & " Where Width = @theWidth")
qd.Parameters("@theWidth") = [Width_Row]
Set rs = qd.OpenRecordset
```

Comment: Amen! Parameters FTW! OP's way is a recipe for SQL injection attacks, or more casually, for poor `Dougal O'Connor` to never be able to register his full name correctly!

Comment: qd.Parameters(@TheWidth) = [Width_Row]
Gives an error due to @ being an "invalid character", when removed, there is an error "Item not found in the collection"

Is there an alternative way to identity the variables in the SQL statement for the parameter input?

Comment: Sorry, missed some quotes there myself. Current edit should work

Comment: Edit
AH thanks I got it! " " work instead of @. everything works now (still brand new @ vba/access, thanks for the fundamentals

Comment: Those @'s are not strictly required. You can just enter any string in place of `@width`. It's a convention I use, which is common to people using T-SQL