# Syntax error for " ' " in Dcount access

Tags: vba, ms-access

In my access database I have records that contain a `'` like `" 2'` " or  `" 5' "`  . When I do a `Dcount` for those items I get a syntax error. Here is the code I use. It seems the `'` is interpreted as the end of the command.

```
If DCount("[myItem]", "MyDB", "[MyItem] = '" & VALUE & "'") > 0 Then
```

`VALUE` is the string variable that captures what the user enter for the count and that contains the `'`

Is there a way around this ?

Comment: You are discovering the nasties of concatenating user input into executable SQL, which is the basis of what's called an [**SQL Injection Attack**](https://xkcd.com/327/). You can try to escape the single quotes in the user's input (double it up), but the only *real solution* is to use parameters, and **never** concatenate user input into executable SQL.

Comment: Hmm sorry, I totally missed that this wasn't a *query* - probably *should be* though. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/48175083/ for an answer that shows how to write a properly parameterized DAO query.

Comment: I just gave you a link...

Comment: I assume I would have the same issues in my next line of code that dose a DLookup. Right ? so to do count in sql I should use SELECT COUNT ?

Comment: Yes, you would :)

Comment: Suman Kabir's option worked as a fix for now. But I will definitively learn to use parameters. I also need to learn how to get the SELECT COUNT result as a variable so I can use it later. Thanks !

Comment: Awesome - make sure you mark Suman Kabir's answer as accepted before you go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
If DCount("[myItem]", "MyDB", "[MyItem] = '" & Replace(VALUE , "'", "''") & "'") > 0 Then
```

Also you can use this :

```
If DCount("[myItem]", "MyDB", "[MyItem] = """ & VALUE & """") > 0 Then
```

Just replacing each single quote `'` to two double quote `""` which will work in ms access.